# Limited number of datacursormode on a scatter plot - Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have an ellipse plot (scatter) and I wish to have only two datacursormode and than get their respective X and Y coordinates. The code attached plot the ellipse and mark a point but how can I limit it and get the coordinates?

Code:

```
clc;
clear;

a=3;  
b=7; 
x0=0;
y0=0;
t=-pi:0.01:pi;
x=x0+a*cos(t);
y=y0+b*sin(t);
sz = 5;
scatter(x,y,sz)

dcm_obj = datacursormode;
set(dcm_obj,'UpdateFcn',@myupdatefcn)

function txt = myupdatefcn(empt,event_obj)
pos1 = get(event_obj,'Position');
txt = {['X position ',num2str(pos1(1))],...
          ['Y position: ',num2str(pos1(2))]};
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a while loop for selecting two points, and use nested functions for sharing variables.

Using nested functions is a possible solution for passing the selected coordinates and a counter out to a parent function.

You can limit the number of selected (marked) points to two, using a while loop.
Placing a `pause` inside the while is important for responsiveness.

Here is a working code sample:

```
function ellip()
%Parent function (use a function instead of a script, 
%allows sharing variables with internal function).

clc;
%clear;

a=3;  
b=7; 
x0=0;
y0=0;
t=-pi:0.01:pi;
x=x0+a*cos(t);
y=y0+b*sin(t);
sz = 5;
h = figure; %Open new figure, and keep the handle.
scatter(x,y,sz);

dcm_obj = datacursormode;
dcm_obj.Enable = 'on';
set(dcm_obj,'UpdateFcn',@myupdatefcn)

%pos_x, pos_y and pos_counter are known both in scope of myupdatefcn and in ellip
pos_x = zeros(1,2);
pos_y = zeros(1,2);
pos_counter = 0;

%Loop until two points are selected
while (pos_counter < 2) && isvalid(h)
    pause(0.01);
end

if isvalid(h)
    close(h); %Close the figure;

    %Display position of the two selected coordinates.
    fprintf('pos1 = (%f, %f), pos2 = (%f, %f)\n', pos_x(1), pos_y(1), pos_x(2), pos_y(2));
end

dcm_obj.delete() %Delete the object (cleanup)

    %myupdatefcn is a nested function, inside ellip function
    function txt = myupdatefcn(empt, event_obj)      
        pos1 = get(event_obj,'Position');
        txt = {['X position ',num2str(pos1(1))],...
               ['Y position: ',num2str(pos1(2))]};
        disp(txt);

        pos_counter = pos_counter + 1; %Increase counter.
        pos_x(pos_counter) = pos1(1);  %Store position
        pos_y(pos_counter) = pos1(2);        
    end

end
```

I hope that I got it right, it is difficult understanding what you are asking...

---

**Update to comment:**

- Creating the scatter plot outside the function is simple.
- Saving the 4 positions is simple - the function can return the points.
- I couldn't find an elegant way for leaving the tool-tip information on the plot.
  The problem is that calling `createDatatip` triggers the event and executes `myupdatefcn` few more times.
  You may take a look at [Set data tips programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29882186/set-data-tips-programmatically)

Updated code:

```
clc
clear
close all

a=3;  
b=7; 
x0=0;
y0=0;
t=-pi:0.01:pi;
x=x0+a*cos(t);
y=y0+b*sin(t);
sz = 5;
scatter(x,y,sz);

[pos_x, pos_y] = ellip();

%Display position of the two selected coordinates.
fprintf('pos1 = (%f, %f), pos2 = (%f, %f)\n', pos_x(1), pos_y(1), pos_x(2), pos_y(2));


function [pos_x, pos_y] = ellip()
%Parent function (use a function instead of a script, 
%allows sharing variables with internal function).

dcm_obj = datacursormode;
dcm_obj.Enable = 'on';
set(dcm_obj,'UpdateFcn',@myupdatefcn)

h = dcm_obj.Figure; %Get hendle to the figure.
hScatter = findobj(h, 'Type', 'scatter'); %Handle to scatter plot

%pos_x, pos_y and pos_counter are known both in scope of myupdatefcn and in ellip
pos_x = zeros(1,2);
pos_y = zeros(1,2);
pos_counter = 0;

%Loop until two points are selected
while (pos_counter < 2) && isvalid(h)
    pause(0.01);   
end

% if isvalid(h)
%     close(h); %Close the figure;    
% end


%dcm_obj.delete() %Delete the object (cleanup)
if isvalid(h)
    dcm_obj.Enable = 'off';
    set(dcm_obj,'UpdateFcn',[]) %Replace the callback with an empty function instead of deleting the object
end

    %myupdatefcn is a nested function, inside ellip function
    function txt = myupdatefcn(empt, event_obj)      
        pos1 = get(event_obj,'Position');

        txt = {['X position ',num2str(pos1(1))],...
               ['Y position: ',num2str(pos1(2))]};

        if (pos_counter > 0) && (pos_x(pos_counter) == pos1(1)) && (pos_y(pos_counter) == pos1(2))
            return %Return if pod1 is already selected.
        end

        disp(txt);

        pos_counter = pos_counter + 1; %Increase counter.
        pos_x(pos_counter) = pos1(1);  %Store position
        pos_y(pos_counter) = pos1(2);

        %Try keeping the tool-tip data
        hdtip = dcm_obj.createDatatip(hScatter);
        set(hdtip, 'MarkerSize',5, 'MarkerFaceColor','none', 'MarkerEdgeColor','r', 'Marker','o', 'HitTest','off');                    
    end
end
```

Comment: Cool. Is it possible that the function will not include the ellipse so it can be called on any scatter plot. How is it possible to leave the Data Cursor Mode Properties on the plot and how can I save the 4 positions (2 sets of x,y) as I can not see them in the workspace.

Comment: I got messed up trying to keep the Data Cursor Mode Properties (tooltip). Please let me know if you find an elegant solution for that.

Comment: It works fine but datacursormode will continue to work/mark more points after the first two sets although there is a limitation in the while loop. Anyway, pos_x and pos_y will record the first two sets.

Comment: @jane Try adding `datacursormode off` at the end.

Comment: Thanks, shell I add it at the end of one the functions, after the while loop?

Comment: @jane I don't think it matters much.

Comment: Thanks for the script. I put the datacursormode off in several places (end of one the functions, after the while loop) but it still mark more than 2 points. Why?

Comment: You are right... I can't figure it out. As an alternative, you can add command `pan on` (it's an improvised solution).